# Alternatives to MVC

Tags: machine-learning, server, dynamically-generated

I am doing some work with machine learning, and the possibility of [generative products](https://medium.com/vvvvvv-studio/generative-products-c2b18fd12708).

MVC (and all [sibling models](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/alternatives-to-mvc.html)) seem to be less than ideal for such thinking.

I wonder if there is a fundamentally different way of architecting backend environment?